# Install Python-Docx on Win 10

Tags: windows, installation, python-docx

I installed Python34 and Python32 on my Win10. Also I downloaded WinPython and tried to add the package 'python-docx' with their control panel. This failed: filenaming not recognized (tar.gz)

Then I tried to install it myself with the cmd. The error was lxml not found. That installation failed because it didnt find Python on my computer. I'm running out of ideas..

Is it really that hard to install python docx?

Answer (score 1):

for Winpython, you may try this:

- click on the "WinPython Command Prompt.exe" icon
- then type on the opened console the following 3 words:

  pip install python-docx

Comment: Where shall I write this? In the WinPython console or cmd of Win10?
In cmd console it returns: 'launch' mispelled or not founf